# ADMX Registry Settings don't get applied

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy

I have created an admx file to set windows background color and wallpaper for Windows Serer 2008 R2 machines in an active directory:

```
<policyDefinitions revision="1.0" schemaVersion="1.0">
    <policyNamespaces>
        <target prefix="fullarmor"
            namespace="FullArmor.Policies.2D936335_9AA1_4320_8BA2_7785BEF119B2" />
        <using prefix="windows" namespace="Microsoft.Policies.Windows" />
    </policyNamespaces>
    <supersededAdm fileName="" />
    <resources minRequiredRevision="1.0" />
    <categories>
        <category name="CAT_APPS" displayName="$(string.CAT_APPS)" />
        <category name="CAT_APPS_DESKTOP" displayName="$(string.CAT_APPS_DESKTOP)">
            <parentCategory ref="CAT_APPS" />
        </category>
    </categories>
    <policies>
        <policy name="POL_APPS_DESKTOP_BACKGROUND" class="User"
            displayName="$(string.POL_APPS_DESKTOP_BACKGROUND)"
            presentation="$(presentation.POL_APPS_DESKTOP_BACKGROUND)" key="Control Panel\Colors">
            <parentCategory ref="CAT_APPS_DESKTOP" />
            <supportedOn ref="windows:SUPPORTED_WindowsVista" />
            <elements>
                <text id="TXT_FCB801FC_18FF_41B1_8B75_A9317DD5995A" key="Control Panel\Colors"
                    valueName="Background" />
            </elements>
        </policy>
        <policy name="POL_APPS_DESKTOP_WALLPAPER" class="User"
            displayName="$(string.POL_APPS_DESKTOP_WALLPAPER)"
            presentation="$(presentation.POL_APPS_DESKTOP_WALLPAPER)" key="Control Panel\Desktop">
            <parentCategory ref="CAT_APPS_DESKTOP" />
            <supportedOn ref="windows:SUPPORTED_WindowsVista" />
            <elements>
                <text id="TXT_74A610D5_1E49_4E38_BB6E_27C82925EADB" key="Control Panel\Desktop"
                    valueName="Wallpaper" />
            </elements>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</policyDefinitions>
```

However, after deploying these settings through a GPO, the registry changes are only applied to existing users after a new login. They are never applied to new users that are created after the deployment of these settings. For new users, the registry keys:

> HKCU\Control Panel\Colors\Background

and

> HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper

are never touched.

Why does the registry not change for new users? What am I doing wrong?

I have attached a screenshot of the settings of the GPO which only contains the above to settings:

[image]

Why is only the registry setting for the wallpaper shown under "Extra Registry Settings"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find a solution. The problem is here that I used physically distinct machines on a corporate network and that the DC did not use a central store for storing the ADMX files.

After creating a central store for ADMX files everything works out.